# How can I log javascript actions?

Tags: php, javascript

Okay, here is a noob question.

I'm building a website with some webplayers in it and I want to log all the user actions such as user clicked on this audio, user pressed pause button, user clicked on next audio...

I want to log all these actions in the server.

The whole website is written in php and javascript. I've heard somewhere that we can only do this using ajax. Is it? Can we do any better?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: The normal way of doing this is to send ajax request inside the javascript actions/methods. Those call a php file with the desired parameters which will do the log entries.

Comment: We develop in ASP.Net and use Log4Net - there's a similar one for Javascript aptly named Log4javascript: http://log4javascript.org/ you can give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use `jaax` for this and `jquery.ajax` is best suitable to you

For egs, you want to capture `click event` then try it like,

```
$(document).on('click','#pauseButton',function(){
   $.ajax({
      url:'yourpage.php',type:'POST',
      data:{your data}
      success:function(response){
          // your response
          console.log(response);
      }
   })
});
```

Read more [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)